# Do I need to open and close a Segger JLink connection when using the dlls to access multiple cores from a single PC process using a licensed SDK

Tags: sdk

Segger allow you to obtain a license for using their JLink SDK.
I am using it to create tooling to allow examination of the state of a new (not yet commercially available) SoC microprocessor that contains multiple cores (multiple ARM cortex M cores and DSPs) with SWD debug H/W.

Segger include a GDB server in their normal software [download](https://www.segger.com/downloads/jlink/JLink_Windows.exe) which can definitely access any single core from a single process.

I do not think Segger makes their [SDK](https://www.segger.com/products/debug-probes/j-link/technology/j-link-sdk/) UM08002 documentation and code samples public but it demonstrates being able to access a single core (which works fine for me).

All the SDK really is is a set of headers and documentation that allow you call into the already distributed SEGGER JLink dll's (the dll's in the normal software [download](https://www.segger.com/downloads/jlink/JLink_Windows.exe) prompts you for auto updating) so there is no magic happening in the SDK itself; but it is licensed so I can't post any of it here.

What I do not understand is what dll calls must be made to access multiple cores sequentially from within a single process using the SDK.

Do I:

- Disconnect and reconnect from the SEGGER every time I wish to access a different core
- Can I switch between cores somehow without opening & closing the JLink connection
- Can I leave the cores halted when switching between cores so the device doesn't 'run off' while I'm looking elsewhere
- Will the core HW & SW debug points remain set & get triggered if I'm looking at a different core and allow me to discover this when I look back at a hopefully now halted core in question? (This may be core implementation dependant of course)

Comment: A "segger" tag would be nice to collate segger related questions. Unfortunately the "jlink" tag has already been nabbed by the java people

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

No, sort of.

**Long answer**

The Segger JLink dll API is a single target per process API, so that means you can't start talking to another core while the process global state held by the dll is configured to talk to another core.  In order to select the target core you have to inject appropriate initialisation scripts written in Seggers 'not quite sinmple c' scripting language.  In order to change the scripts and ensure they have all run appropriately then you need to close down you connection to the target, set the new scripts and then reopen a connection to the new target core.

It is possible to adjust some details on the fly by executing some commands in a 'key=value' language but you can't do everything you might need to that way.

**Recommended approach**

What you can do is have multiple process sharing a JLink.

Each process initialised to a specific target core and then they share the JLink automatically on an API cal by API call basis.  For compound, multiple api call, operations you need to serialise these operations using the dll API JLinkARM_Lock() and JLinkArm_Unlock() or you can potentially get processes 'jumping in' during these compound operations and having their behaviour become undefined or unreliable.

They to communicate with multiple target cores you do some inter process communication from your master process to your spawned JLink operation processes.

Remember to include keep alives in you inter process communication so that crashes or debugging doesn't result in a plethora of orphaned or silent processes.